# How can I detect if an object is an ILookup<,> and print it?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to make a very rudimentary generic object printer for debugging, inspired by the awesomeness you get in LinqPad.

Below is the pseudocode for my print function. My reflection-foo is kind of weak at the moment and I'm struggling to deal with the case when the object is an ILookup, as I'd like enumerate the lookup, printing each key alongside its associated collection.

ILookup doesn't have a non-generic interface and it doesn't implement IDictionary, so I'm kind of stuck at the moment, as I can't say `o as ILookup<object,object>`...  For that matter, I'd like to know how to delve into any generic interface...suppose I'd like to have a special case for `CustomObject<,,>`.

```
void Print(object o)
{
    if(o == null || o.GetType().IsValueType || o is string)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(o ?? "*nil*");
         return;
    }

    var dict = o as IDictionary;     
    if(dict != null)
    {
        foreach(var key in (o as IDictionary).Keys)
        {
            var value = dict[key];
            Print(key + " " + value);
        }
        return;
    }

    //how can i make it work with an ILookup? 
    //????????? 


    var coll = o as IEnumerable;
    if(coll != null)
    {
        foreach(var item in coll)
        { print(item); }
        return;
    }

    //else it's some object, reflect the properties+values
    {
        //reflectiony stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This also might be easier with polymorphism, i.e., `void Print(IDictionary dict)`, `void Print(IEnumerable ienum)`, `void Print(object o)`, etc.

Comment: @mellamokb - I thought so too. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but the mutually recursive `Print` calls don't behave as you'd expect.

Comment: According to @xanatos, `ILookup` is an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`.  It looks like your current code should work as-is.  What happens if you pass in an object of type `ILookup`?

Comment: @Kobi: I found I also had to add in `void Print(string s)` for it to work properly.

Comment: As a note, I deleted my response because my way of "discovering" if an object is a ILookup was wrong (I only checked for the Lookup implementation). The IEnumerable of IEnumerable is true and works BUT he will "lose" the "key" part. The IEnumerable of IEnumerable will only give him the value part.

Comment: If you're still interested in this problem, are you interested in collaborating on [ExpressionToCode](http://code.google.com/p/expressiontocode/)?  That necessarily includes a generic object printer, but it doesn't have a special case for `ILookup<>` yet :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly, but to answer your specific question, you can use reflection like this:

```
public static void PrintIfLookup(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    // Find first implemented interface that is a constructed version of
    // ILookup<,>, or null if no such interface exists.
    var lookupType = obj
                    .GetType()
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .FirstOrDefault
                     (i => i.IsGenericType &&
                           i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILookup<,>));

    if (lookupType != null)
    {
        // It is an ILookup<,>. Invoke the PrintLookup method
        // with the correct type-arguments.

        // Method to invoke is private and static.
        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;

        // Assuming the containing type is called Foo.
        typeof(Foo).GetMethod("PrintLookup", flags)
                   .MakeGenericMethod(lookupType.GetGenericArguments())
                   .Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
    }

}

private static void PrintLookup<TKey, TElement>(ILookup<TKey, TElement> lookup)
{
    // TODO: Printing logic    
}
```

I've tried to write it in such a way that you can write the printing logic in a strongly-typed manner with generics. If you prefer, you can instead do even more reflection to get the key and values out of each `IGrouping<,>` in the lookup.

**EDIT**: By the way, if you are on C# 4, you can replace the entire body of the `if` statement with:

```
PrintLookup((dynamic)obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism might make your code a little simpler.

```
void Print(IDictionary dict)
{
    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
        var value = dict[key];
        Print(key + " " + value);
    }
}

void Print(object o)
{
    if (o == null || o.GetType().IsValueType || o is string)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o ?? "*nil*");
        return;
    }
}

void Print(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

void Print(IEnumerable ie)
{
    foreach (dynamic obj in ie)
    {
        Print(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was also my problem, you need to use `dynamic`, which to be honest, I'd like to avoid. Assembly, you'd want to use dynamic formatting on `IDictionary` keys/values, `ILookup`, etc.

Comment: @Kobi: Is there really a difference between `dynamic` and reflection?  They both move type checking to runtime, and `dynamic` can be more succinct for expressing particular applications like this.

Comment: You are right, `dynamic` is much better here, it simplifies reflection a great deal. Specifically, it eliminates `if`s on types and many `as`/`is`, which I don't care for. I was hoping for no reflection at all, not to more `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To determine that the type implements some generic interface using reflection:

```
var objType = o.GetType();

// get the ILookup<,> interface type (if the type implements it)
var lookupInterface = objType.GetInterface("System.Linq.ILookup`2");

// the type implemented the interface if returned non-null value
var isILookup = lookupInterface != null;
```

The pattern for the name mangling for generic types is

```
type_name`generic_parameter_count
```

For a specific instance of a generic type:

```
type_name`generic_parameter_count[type_name_1,...,type_name_n]
```

In this case, `ILookup<,>` had two parameters so it's:

```
System.Linq.ILookup`2
```

We're not interested in the exact instance so we don't need to specify the type parameters.

Comment: @Ani: Everyone else is thinking the same thing... but is there a better solution?

Comment: @mellamokb: Yes, there is. The trick is to call `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on the constructed generic type.

Comment: @Ani: It doesn't make it any less safe or less efficient.  _Searching_ for the type isn't necessary if you know what the exact name of the type that you are looking for.  It's an option yes but this approach is just as good.  Now people might not be comfortable with this approach due to unfamiliarity or whatever and that's understandable, but it doesn't make it bad.

Comment: @Jeff: IMO, it does make it less safe. There could be a different interface with that name. Btw, I agree that what I say is just my opinion. This technique is more succinct, but I prefer not to use strings for type-names when there are other alternatives available.

Comment: @Ani: Not if the fully-qualified names are used as I have here.  There is no ambiguity here so that is not an issue.

Comment: @Jeff: Not really. Try creating an ambiguous interface in your own project. The compiler gives you a warning, but lets it through. Fully qualified names are only unique within an assembly.

Comment: @And: Which can be resolved using the right string.  Something that cannot be resolved as easily any other way.  How would your solution have changed to handle that?  Sorry, I'm not seeing eye-to-eye with you on this one.

Comment: Let say you stopped referencing `System.Core.dll` / made a typo in the string. The string solution will still compile. The `typeof(..)` solution won't. Anyway, I'm not making a big deal of this. Reflection is prone to errors anyway; I just prefer not to use strings to represent types when there are alternatives.